# How to elegantly prevent fixed-position tables laid on top of each other in CSS?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

Ok, I have 1st table that hold the header. I also have 2nd table to hold err message, a 3rd table to hold content, 4th table to hold footer.

I want the 1st & 2nd table to be fixed, ie when the 3rd one has more content & when user scroll down the 1st & 2nd one still stay intact.

So here is what i did.

```
<table style='width:100%;position: fixed;' border="0"> some header widgets here </table>
<br/><br/><br/>
<table style='width:100%;position: fixed;' border="0"> err message here</table>
<br/><br/><br/>
<table> content widgets here </table>
<br/>
<table> footer widgets here</table>
```

It seems to work fine, but i am not sure it is elegant, The reason is I have to use `<br/><br/><br/>` after the the 1st table & after the 2nd one. If i don't do that then the 1st, 2nd & 3rd one will be chucked on top of each other. But if i put more `<br/>` then i may create some unnecessary gaps between them.

So what is the right way to handle this problem (the fixed position table laid on top of each other) in CSS?

I don't like dive cos i have to crack my head everytime i do Div, & besides my website structure is very simple so table is my choice & i don't need Div.

Note: I am using GWT platform, so the table is actually wrapped inside a HTMLPanel (that is invented by Google so they must make sure all the stuffs inside HTMLPanel work well)

Comment: don't use tables. Flow layout will be far more elegant. Tables should only be used for tabular data.

Comment: Also your tables have no rows or columns, so they are invalid HTML.

Comment: some one with 12K reputation suggested me to use table

Comment: @Liam this is just a skeleton from OP, i think. Not the actual table.

Comment: @Kiti dont go for repo's. go for appropriate solution.

Comment: I'm sure they didn't say to use tables like this. This HTML is invalid. and will display very weird on different browsers.

Comment: my web site structure is very simple : the header- the content- the footer, so i don;t ike something complicated. everytime i use Div, my head got exploded.

Comment: But your tables above are basically div's.

Comment: Can you cite the comment, answer or chat, where this 12k user suggested that you use tables?

Comment: ok, inside that table, there a lot of small widgets. If i use Div , then i have to change Div for all these small widgets & that is very headache

Comment: forgot the link, but when a guy said if he can use some layoutpanel he said, put table inside HTML made it easier for u to control. So he implied to use table

Comment: Note: I am using GWT platform, so the table is actually wrapped inside a HTMLPanel (that is invented by Google so they must make sure all the stuffs inside HTMLPanel work well)

Comment: @Liam, my table has contents inside, it has rows & columns inside to hold small widgets inside it

Answer (score 0):

Like Liam said, don't use tables for your web page structure. It's slow, bad practice and difficult to maintain. Take a look and read through this.

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_structural_elements

Comment: I using Gwt platform & some Gwt guys with 16K reputation told me to use table for simplicity

Comment: Tables are extremely bad structure. Regardless of their rep, or my rep go do research yourself. Personally, I've trained from lynda.com which is best practice as well as being on a web development apprenticeship being taught by an expert face to face. I'm just relaying what I know. Tables cause problems, something which you've already come across. I actually find it simpler not using tables but not may just be me. If you want my advice, and that of current experts. Use HTML5 and use proper structure, not tables. Tables are for tabular data, not to structure your site. Look at the HTML spec.

Comment: I knew many web designer use tool like dreamweaver to make the layout so the Dreamweaver do all things for them, i code the layout by hand without any supporting tool & i feel very hard to control Div, I don't know why there is any problem with table since it very easy to understand, very easy to use & Google uses it in google.com

Comment: I just took a look at some Google source code and from what I could see they've used divs. Divs are difficult to control, which is why I use HTML5. HTML5 is fantastic in my opinion and very simple to follow and manipulate. The great thing about coding is that it's all about what you, as the coder, are most comfortable doing. You do it how you want. Personally, I'm not comfortable with tables for structure so I use HTML5 for tags such as header, and section. You're obviously more comfortable with tables. It's all about what you like :)